# Modificar valor en celda DatagridView cada vez pulsa una tecla

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms, datagridview

Tengo un datagridview donde se escribe un numero con decimales, si se escribe por ejemplo 12.45 yo quiero ser capaz de cambiarlo por 12,45.
Es decir, quiero ver cada vez que se pulsa una tecla en la celda si es un punto (.) y si lo es cambiarlo por una coma (,)
He intentado hacerlo usando el CellValidated, CellValidating y CellValueChanged pero no lo consigo.

Por ejemplo en el cell validated lo he intentado asi:

```
    Dim columna As Int16
    Dim valor As String
    columna = dgvHWComprado.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    If (columna = 6) Then
        valor = dgvHWComprado(6, dgvHWComprado.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value
        valor.Replace(".", ",")
        dgvHWComprado(6, dgvHWComprado.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value = valor
    End If
```

Agradeceria si alguien me dice cual es el mejor evento para conseguir esto.
Un saludo.

Comment: intenta con el evento CellEndEdit

Comment: gracias @Manny pero el tema es que usando ese evento al llegar el momento de la comprobacion del valor ya ha cambiado el valor, no me recupera lo que yo he escrito sino que lo transforma, por ejemplo 1.65 lo pasa a 165 directamente, no consigo pillar el 1.65

Comment: utiliza el codigo ASCII para detectar la tecla que estas pulsando y en ese momento lo cambias a la 'coma', podrias usar el evento CellValueChnaged.

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente instrucción no modifica la variable valor:

```
valor.Replace(".", ",")
```

Tienes que asignar el resultado del Replace a una variable, que puede ser ella misma:

```
valor = valor.Replace(".", ",")
```